# How to make iframe previews unique to each post. My previews are all showing the same content of the last post on the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, while-loop

I'm trying to debug an issue with my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Each post on my wordpress site has a span that when focused on through the `:focus` CSS, reveals an iframe popup which is a preview of a link in the post which has a Unique ID equivalent to the Post ID.

Example of the links from the Admin Dashboard for posting on Wordpress:

```
Post 356 Content:
<a id="link356" href="www.exampleone.com"></a>

Post 411 Content:
<a id="link411" href="www.exampletwo.com"></a>

Post 202 Content:
<a id="link202" href="www.examplethree.com"></a>

Post 540 Content:
<a id="link540" href="www.examplefour.com"></a>
```

The link in the full code below with the `class="myPreButton"` is located under each post, this pops up an iframe, but the iframe is only previewing the last post inside the loop, rather than each preview loading each post separately.

`$('iframe').attr('src', $("a#link" + theID).attr("href"));`

This code is targetting each individuals posts link ID and making the Src of the iframe that link.

So my problem is, Post 356, 411, 202, and 540 all share the same preview content that is being pulled from `id="link540"` which is the last post on the page.

I'm assuming the problem has something to do with the PostID in the script itself or something to do with the loop.

Here's my code below:

```
   <?php 
    if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="content">
                        <!-- EXAMPLE LINKS FROM ABOVE -->

    <p class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                        <!-- EXAMPLE LINKS FROM ABOVE -->
    </div>

<div class="preview">
    <a id="p2" class="myPreButton" href='javascript:void();' >
<span class="text">                          
    <div class="iframe-preview">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function link_ID(){

    var theID = '<?php the_ID(); ?>';

    $("a.myPreButton").hover(function(){  
         $('iframe').attr('src', $("a#link" + theID).attr("href"));                                 
                     }); });
            </script>

            <iframe id="iframe-preview" src="" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="iframe-preview-content" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="2000px" width="1000px"></iframe>

    </div>           
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;
else :
echo '<p>No content found</p>';
endif;
?>
```

Comment: You're defining `the_ID()` here as a Javascript function then trying to use it as if it were PHP. I'm also assuming `$post = the_post(); ` won't work as `the_post()` is PHP, not Javascipt.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Lewis. I ajusted some of the code by removing `$post = the_post();` entirley and nothing changed, so you're correct in that it wasn't working at all and is not needed. In regards to the first part of your answer when defining `the_ID()` are you reffering to `funtion the_ID(){` that I had or `var theID = '<?php the_ID(); ?>';` ? Thanks

Comment: After another look, it appears as though you are replacing your hover event on every iteration of the while loop. This means that you will only end up with the ID that was attached to the last iteration - and would explain your problem. You will probably have to change your approach - output an **a** link for every post (in the php). On this link, add a data attribute for the post ID. This way, you can retrieve the post ID as part of the hover event unique to each A. If you don’t figure it out before tomorrow, I’ll post an example as I’m on mobile right now.

Comment: Hey Lewis, thanks! I tried what you had suggested but didn't seem to work. Not sure if I did it right though. If you don't mind posting that example, would be much appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, here's my suggestion;

1. Add a data-postid to each `a` link that contains the *post_id*
2. Also add a data-postid to each iframe containing the *post_id* to create a link between `a` and `iframe`.
3. Use these in your javascript;

```js
    $("a.myPreButton").hover(function(){
        let post_id = $(this).data("postid"); // This now contains your post id!
        let iframe = $("iframe[data-postid='" + post_id + "']"); // This gets the correct iframe using the post_id to match!
        let href = $(this).attr("href") + post_id; // This creates your new src

        iframe.attr('src', href); // This gets the current href and appends the postid
    })
```

```html
<div class="preview">
    <a id="p2" class="myPreButton" href='javascript:void();' data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <span class="text">  <span class="text">
    </a>

    <div class="iframe-preview">
        <iframe id="iframe-preview" src="" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="iframe-preview-content" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="2000px" width="1000px" data-postid="<?php the_ID(); ?>"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```